# Converting mongo array to object with key-value pair

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-aggregation

I have a mongo document that contains an array of Strings, and I need to convert this particular array of strings into an array of object containing a key-value pair. Below is my curent appraoch to it.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57e3720836e36f63695a2ef2"),
    "platform" : "A1",
    "available" : {
        "Community" : {
            "attributes" : {
                "type" : {
                    "values" : [
                        "well-known",
                        "simple",
                        "complex"
                    ],
                    "defaultValue" : "well-known"
                },
[......]


}
```

**Current Query:**

```
templateAttributes.find({platform:"V1"}).map(function(c){
  //instantiate a new array
  var optionsArray = [];
for (var i=0;i< c['available']['Community']['attributes']['type']['values'].length; i++){
    optionsArray[i] = {};              // creates a new object
    optionsArray[i].label = c['available']['Community']['attributes']['type']['values'][i];
    optionsArray[i].value = c['available']['Community']['attributes']['type']['values'][i];
    }
    return optionsArray;
})[0];
```

**Result:**

```
[{label:"well-known", value:"well-known"},
{label:"simple", value:"simple"},
{label:"complex", value:"complex"}]
```

Is my approach efficient enough, or is there a way to optimize the above query to get the same desired result?

Comment: Any specific reasons this has to be done on mongodb side ?

Comment: No. There is no specific reason it needs to be done on the mongo side. Since I'm using this in Meteor, this query is run in memory (mini-mongo).

Comment: @bluereen Ok. Then aggregate is the solution. Just keep in mind that `$unwind` will multiply the result set size array.length times. So use a `$project` before to just keep required fields, perhaps only 'values'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not so sure what you want to do with the end result as the keys and the values are just the same. Nonetheless, you can use the aggregation framework
where you can denormalise the embedded values array by using the **[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind)** operator which flattens it i.e. it produces a copy of each document per array entry.

After flattening the values array, you can apply the **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** accumulation operators on the values to aggregate them. A final pipeline of the **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** operator would shape the fields from the previous grouping into the desired format.

Follow this example to get the concept:

```
templateAttributes.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "platform": "V1" } },
    { "$unwind": "$available.Community.attributes.type.values" },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$available.Community.attributes.type.values",
            "value": { "$first": "$available.Community.attributes.type.values" }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "label": "$_id",
            "value": 1
        }
    }
])
```

---

Since you are using Meteor, meteor add **[`meteorhacks:aggregate`](https://atmospherejs.com/meteorhacks/aggregate)** will add proper aggregation support for Meteor so that you can run the above aggregation pipeline on your collection.

Comment: I intend to pass them to a HTML <options> menu. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Chris. I'm still debating on the package and the whole aggegate query since the package only does things at server side. Added to that, I'm using autoforms and feeding the dropdown data from the mongo query on client side

Answer (score 3):

Please use aggregation here.

```
db.templateAttributes.aggregate([
                                    {"$match":{platform:"A1"}}, {"$unwind": "$available.Community.attributes.type.values"}, 
                                    {$group: {"_id": null, "val":{"$push":{label:"$available.Community.attributes.type.values", 
                                                                            value:"$available.Community.attributes.type.values"}}}}
                                ]).toArray()[0].val
```

**Output:**

```
[
    {
            "label" : "well-known",
            "value" : "well-known"
    },
    {
            "label" : "simple",
            "value" : "simple"
    },
    {
            "label" : "complex",
            "value" : "complex"
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll give this a shot and get revert.

Answer (score 0):

Use query

```
  templateAttributes.aggregate([{
$match: {
    "platform" : "A1"
    }},
    {
    $unwind: {path : "$available.Community.attributes.type.values"}},{   $group:{
    _id:"$_id",
    result:{
        $push: {
            label: "$available.Community.attributes.type.values", value: "$available.Community.attributes.type.values"
            }
        }
    }}])
```

It'll give you exact your expected answer.