# How to transform json array to key/value pairs with predefined key values

Tags: arrays, json, mongodb

I have an output from an API that is loaded to MongoDB with a structure like this:

```
{
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "654e74b1325312179d479295"
    },
    "myid": "id123",
    "array": [ 7, 98, 2, 35, 76 ],
  }
```

Every entry in the arrays have a different measure value and the measures are identified by their position in the array. I do have the name of the measures as a constant and I would like to transform the original arrays as a key/value pair.

The measure names are: [“val0”, “val1”, “val2”, “val3”, “val4”] and they are not part of the API output. I got it from the written documentation.

I have a Python code that iterate over the arrays and output a new structure but I would like to eliminate this extra step and try to do it with MongoDB without Python.

I would like to have the output something like this:

"array": [ {“val0”: 7}, {“val1”:  98}, {“val2”: 2}, {“val3”: 35}, {“val4”: 76} ],

I have tried to find a similar situation to start from but I was unable to find any.

-- Update --

The closest I got was following [Converting mongo array to object with key-value pair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39653872/converting-mongo-array-to-object-with-key-value-pair)

I used the code:

```
db.array_test.aggregate([{
    $match: {
        "myid" : "id123"
        }},
           {
        $unwind: {path : "$array"}},{   $group:{
        _id:"$_id",
        result:{
            $push: {
                label: "$array", value: "$array.values"
                }
            }
        }}])
```

and I got:

```
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "654e74b1325312179d479295"
    },
    "result": [
      {
        "label": 7
      },
      {
        "label": 98
      },
      {
        "label": 2
      },
      {
        "label": 35
      },
      {
        "label": 76
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I still need to use the measure names list instead of "label".

Comment: This should be pretty simple with `zip`, `map`, or `reduce`, have you tried those?

Comment: I have tried $map and it could work if I already had the key values in the original jason and even so, it does not produce what I need. It could produce something like {"7": 7} for the first array element. I do not see how either zip or reduce would be a solution. Do you have a sample code available? I would like to try.

Comment: What is the guarantee that `”array": [ 7, 98, 2, 35, 76 ]”` will always match `[“val0”, “val1”, “val2”, “val3”, “val4”]`

Comment: Position 0 will always be measure0, positon1 is measure1 and so on. There are about 14 arrays with 34 elements each I need to work with. In all arrays the measure position is always the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the idea given by @Joe in comment, you can use `$zip` to construct the pairs by measures and the value in `array`. Then wrangle it to an array of k-v tuples and use `$arrayToObject` to convert it. Finally use `$merge` to update back to the collection.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$set": {
      "array": {
        "$let": {
          "vars": {
            "measures": [
              "val0",
              "val1",
              "val2",
              "val3",
              "val4"
            ]
          },
          "in": {
            "$zip": {
              "inputs": [
                "$$measures",
                "$array"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "array": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$array",
          "as": "element",
          "in": {
            "$arrayToObject": [
              [
                {
                  "k": {
                    "$first": "$$element"
                  },
                  "v": {
                    "$last": "$$element"
                  }
                }
              ]
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$merge": {
      "into": "_id",
      "on": "_id"
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SXoFZY0HGdH)

Comment: That is a good solution. I got partial results using different approaches but I couldn't put all the parts together. This is the output I needed. Thanks.